# DeprecationWarning: A boolean value was passed to options.operatorsAliases. This is a no-op with v5 and should be removed

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I'm getting the below error in ExpressJS with Sequelize:

```
DeprecationWarning: A boolean value was passed to options.operatorsAliases. This is a no-op with v5 and should be removed.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is not an error, it's simply a warning stating that passing boolean values to `operatorsAliases` in sequelize `options` will be deprecated in v5.

To remove the warning, replace the boolean value by `'1'` or `'0'` for true and false respectively.

Comment: @leochet I have changed the boolean value to Integer but Still showing the same error.

Comment: @Rabbani_ did you use integers or strings containing the digits?

Comment: I am using Integer .

Comment: you need a string

Comment: This really isn't an appropriate answer, and doesn't solve anything.

Comment: This is the appropriate answer, as far as i tested it. However, if you use the logging option, you should make it 0 (int), not '0' (string), or else it will throw an error. You should change all options you provide to sequelize options of type boolean to  0 (if false) and 1 (if true)

Answer (score 16):

Based on my experience

Go to your file

`app\models\index.js`

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
...
    operatorsAliases: 0, // change this to zero

...
);
```

run again

`"node server.js"`

Comment: Thanks might not be the best solution but was what make me notice what this was referencing to.

Answer (score 5):

The `operatorsAliases` as a boolean no longer exists.  If you were simply setting it to `false` before, you can completely remove `operatorsAliases` from your config.  It only existed as a backwards compatibility option.

Answer (score 5):

Go app\models\index.js
and change **operatorsAliases** false to zero

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    operatorsAliases: 0, // change false to zero
}
```

[image]